# Pandas pd.cut ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and series with the same number of rows.

The result of `pd.cut` also outputs data with the same shape.

Where am I going wrong?

My dataframe, 37459 rows:

```
df.shape

(37459, 124)
```

The column I am trying to cut, 37459 rows:

```
df['score']

2        74.390244
4        29.268293
5        45.121951
6        46.341463
7        31.707317
           ...    
43502    21.951220
43503     1.219512
43505     3.658537
43506     8.536585
43507    12.195122
Name: score, Length: 37459, dtype: float64
```

And the output of pd.cut:

```
pd.cut(df['score'], [0, 33, 66, 100], labels=[1,2,3], retbins=True, right=False)

(2        3
 4        1
 5        2
 6        2
 7        1
         ..
 43502    1
 43503    1
 43505    1
 43506    1
 43507    1
 Name: score, Length: 37459, dtype: category
 Categories (3, int64): [1 < 2 < 3], array([  0,  33,  66, 100]))
```

My attempt to attach the result of `pd.cut` to the df. I am trying to cut it into three groups and label them `[1,2,3]`:

```
df['score_cut'] = pd.cut(df['score'], [0, 33, 66, 100], labels=[1,2,3], retbins=True, right=False)


ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: If you set `retbins=False` your code should work.

Answer (score 1):

`retbins=True` makes `pd.cut()` return you a tuple. (See the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html).)

```
df['score_cut'], bins = pd.cut(df['score'], [0, 33, 66, 100], labels=[1,2,3], retbins=True, right=False)
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

Did you try qcut?

```
pd.qcut(df['score'], [0, .33, .66, 1], labels=[1,2,3], retbins=True, right=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because this of `df['score_cut']` the shape of this is not equal to the right.